# Is it possible to live long by switching between random walks that each die fast?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk, gambling

Let us have $a<0<b$, and $k$ random walks (games). Given $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, let $X_1^j,X_2^j,\dots$ be discrete random variables with identical distributions (but can be different for different $j$), such that $X_i^j$ represents the gain/loss at round $i$ in game $j$. Let $S_i^j=\sum_{k=1}^iX_k^j$. Let $T_n^j$ be a stopping time such that either $S_{T^j}^j\leq a$ or $S_{T^j}^j\geq b$. For all $i,j$ we have the following: $E(T^j)\leq c(b-a)^2$ for some constant $c$ (not depending on $a,b$), $E(X_i^j)=0$, $Var(X_i^j)>0$, and all the variables $X_i^j$ are mutually independent.

Let us now consider the following game: At each time $i$ we choose one of the $k$ games to play, and we play this chosen game once before moving to the next time step. Mathematically speaking, let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ and $G_1,G_2,\dots$ be random variables, s.t. $X_i$ represents the effect at round $i$, and $G_i$ represents the game chosen at step $i$. Then it holds that $X_i=X_i^{G_i}$, and the total gain/loss at step $i$ is $S_i=\sum_{k=1}^i X_k$.

We can now define a stopping time $T$ as $S_{T}\leq -a$ or $S_T\geq b$.

The question is: Does there exist some constant $d$, that does not depend on $a,b$, such that $E(T)\leq d(b-a)^2$ regardless of our strategy?

Intuitively it should hold, but every attempt I made to show this has failed thus far... If $k=1$ them it holds trivially. I can also solve it if each of the $k$ games has only two possible outcomes, where in game $j$ at each step we either gain $a_j$ with probability $p_j$ or lose $\frac{a_jp_j}{1-p_j}$ with probability $1-p_j$ (mean is zero). In such case we can "simulate" each of the $k$ games by a game that gives +1/-1 with equal probabilities (one step of game $j$ is "flipping fair coin until we reach either $a_j$ or $-\frac{a_jp_j}{1-p_j}$"), and thus the choice of which of the $k$ games we chose does not matter as it can be viewed as always flipping the fair coin. Thus in this case the expected number of steps is $E(T)\leq d(b-a)^2$ for some $d$. However when the structure of the individual games is more complicated, for example when $X_i^j$ can take on multiple values (potentially even infinitely many) I have no idea how to show this...

edit: I managed to show this holds if there exists $m$ such that each $|X_i^j|<m$ using martingales and stopping times, however the case with unbounded $|X_i^j|$ still eludes me. In the bounded case we can construct a martingale $M_i=(S_i)^2 - \sum_{j=1}^i Var(X_j\mid F_{j-1})$, then show that $Var(X_j\mid F_{j-1})$ is always bounded from below by a constant to argue that $E(T)<\infty$ in order to apply optional stopping theorem, from which we get the result. The problem with unbounded $|X_i^j|$ is that we cannot bound $S_T$ with a finite value. And the idea of "bounding too large steps" from [Expected stopping time in bounded random walk with unbounded steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1052952/ajdy) does not seem usable, as the bounded random variables may satisfy $E(X_i^x)<0$ while $E(X_i^y)>0$, thus we cannot construct the submartingale/supermartingale...

Comment: I wonder if it'd be possible to simplify the notation here a bit. The idea is interesting but a bit hard to parse.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that any stopping times $T_n^j$ with the properties you describe exist.  Could you give an example of one?

Comment: We know the individual stopping times $T_n^j$ exist, walks where they dont exist are excluded. An example could be a fair coin toss with +1/-1 with equal probability. Then the stopping time in such coin tossing has $E(T_n^j)\leq n^2$, while $E(X_i^j)=0$ and $Var(X_i^j)>0$.

Comment: [You previously asked-and-deleted this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4595852/) Please note that this kind of behaviour is likely to cause automatic systems to limit your ability to post further questions.

Comment: If $X_n^j = \pm 1$ with equal probability, $E[T_n^j] = \infty$.  This is why it wasn't obvious to me that it's possible to have $E[T_n^j] < \infty$.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have made a mistake, the walks are supposed to be bounded from above as well. I have rewritten it now. I apologize for mixing it up.